# Declaring a variable as more than one interface

Tags: java, variable-declaration

Is there a way to specify a type that is more than one interface, and have the type check be done at compile time?

Example: Let's say I have a method like

```
void method (Object o) { ... }
```

But I want to constrain `o` at compile time to something that implements both `java.lang.reflect.Member` *and* `java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement` (e.g. `Class`, `Field`, `Method`, etc.), and access the methods of both interfaces ideally without casting `o`.

There are plenty of ways to do this at run-time, I'm just specifically curious about a compile-time check.

Comment: @mszymborski Sure but I can't modify existing classes (like `java.lang.reflect.Field`) to implement it.

Comment: Do you mean `<T extends Member & AnnotatedElement> void method(T o)`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Whoa. I had no idea you could do that. That's exactly the answer, you should post it. Thanks! (Sorry, resueman beat you to it!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with generics. Define your method like this:

```
<T extends Member & AnnotatedElement> void method (T o){ /* ... */ }
```

Comment: [Whoa, cool.](http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/2013/10/tim-and-eric-mind-blown.gif) Thanks!